# Print part by part of an String using recurssion

Tags: c#, recursion

I wrote one function via for loop to print part by part of a String using recursion but am not able to formulate the same logic via recursion.

```
 public static List<String> list = new List<string>();

 public static void sample(String str,int length,int num)
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i+num  <= length; i++)
            {
                list.Add(str.Substring(i,num));
            }

        }
```

sample("sample",6,2)
output:
sa
am
mp
pl
le

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: your code works, what is the output you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to this:

```
public static List<String> GroupString(String input, int take, List<String> output) {
    if (input.Length > take)
    {
        output.Add(new String(input.Take(take).ToArray()));
        return GroupString(new string(input.Skip(take).ToArray()), take, output);
    }
    else {
        output.Add(input);
        return output;
    }
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
var testString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et";
var result = GroupString(testString, 5, new List<String>());
```